# CSS Ionic 1 funciona corretamente no Android, mas não no iPhone OSx

Tags: css, ionic, sass, osx

Meu layout, algumas coisas nele, funcionam muito bem no Android com Windows. Mudando para o Mac OSx, criando o projeto e copiando tudo. Quando rodo como

```
ionic server
```

ou

```
ionic server --lab
```

Ambos ficam sem meus CSS aplicados corretamente. Tando no iPhone, quanto no Android.

Como aplicar meu CSS correto no MAC OSx? Utilizo o Ionic 1.

Comment: Pesquisei bastante e tudo que achei de erros semelhantes apontavam para má instalação. Você tentou realizar novamente a instação?

Comment: Vou tentar fazer novamente...